# How can I use system keys in a Microsoft Live Mesh remote desktop session

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-control, windows-live-mesh

I'm using the remote desktop feature from the Windows Live Essentials to connect to my computer at home and noticed some differences. When I do some while at work shortcut like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> would change the tab in the open remote session.

While doing so from somewhere else would change the tabs of the host system. What would I have to configure to turn the forwarding of system keys to the remote system on?

Comment: All Computers are running Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alt-Tab works completely on remote box when Remote Desktop Connection is opened in full screen mode.

---

You can use also the following special Remote Desktop key combinations:

**Alt + Page Up**

Switches between programs from left to right.

**Alt + Page Down**

Switches between programs from right to left.

**Alt + Insert**

Cycles through the programs in the order they were started.

**Alt + Home**

Displays the Start menu.

**Ctrl + Alt + Break**

Switches the client between a window and full screen.

**Ctrl + Alt + End**

Opens the Microsoft Windows NT Security dialog box

**Ctrl + Alt + Pause**

Toggles between fullscreen and windowed mode
(note that this does not set the client desktop to the correct size)

**Alt + Del**

Displays the Windows menu

**Ctrl + Alt + Num -**

Places a snapshot of the client's active window on the clipboard

**Ctrl + Alt + Num +**

Places a snapshot of the client's entire desktop area on the clipboard

Comment: I know I'm not the original questioner, but I *never knew* about Alt-PageUp/Down. Thanks!